# set UITextField.text from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two views, and i'm trying to show text that i getting from first view in `UITextField` of another . Second view shown by - ([source](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNBlurModalView)) so methods ViewWillAppear and ViewDidLoad won't work. And viewDidLoad method of second view is runs when app is started.

I'm tried to make method of second class

secondClass.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemName;//all hooked up in storyboard
-(void)SetName:(NSString *)name;
```

secondClass.m:

```
-(void)SetName:(NSString *)name{
    NSLog(@"%@",name);
    itemName.text = name;//itemName - textField
}
```

and use it in first one:

```
secondViewConroller *secondView = [[secondViewConroller alloc]init];
[secondView SetName:@"Bill"];
```

`NSlog` shows "Bill" but `textField.text` won't change anything.

My guess that app shows UITextField without changes because it shows second view that it gets from viewDidLoad method and i need to update it somehow

**My question**: What is the best approach to change attributes of UI elements from different classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution: There's was something wrong with calling method SetName: with parameters that i getting from first `UIViewController`.

Basically the solution is : create `NSObject` and put in there value from first `UIViewConroller` and then use it in second.

This [TUTORIAL](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-link-fixed.html) helped me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

secondViewConroller.h :

```
@property NSString * conversationName;
```

secondViewConroller.m :

```
@synthesize conversationName;

-(void)SetName:(NSString *)name{
    NSLog(@"%@",name);
    itemName.text = conversationName
}
```

On alloc:

```
secondViewConroller *secondView = [[secondViewConroller alloc]init];
conversationName = @"Set this text";
[secondView SetName:@"Bill"];
```

I would suggest you to read about Protocols after that.

Comment: it's basically the same that i wrote but with nsstring property. I'm having the same result

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:
in 
secondViewConroller.h :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringName;
```

secondViewConroller.m :

```
@synthesize stringName;
```

and in viewDidLoad method you write this line

```
itemName.text = stringName
```

On alloc:

```
secondViewConroller *secondView = [[secondViewConroller alloc]init];
secondView.stringName = @"Set this text";
```

Comment: as i said in my question, method viewDidLoad launches when app is started

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: What if he wants to edit property of existing viewController? I would suggest create protocol with delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

guess there is something wrong with your itemName variable if it appears to get to the nslog.
did you create a referencing outlet in the interface builder for the textfield?
otherwise you can get the right textfield by tag, in IB put for instance tag 1 on the textfield and do in code:

```
UITextField *tf=(UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
tf.text=name;
```

(replace self.view for the view holding the textfield, if not directly in the main view)

Comment: text field is working if i'm changing it in second class (where it's created). The problem is with changing it from first class

Comment: btw, you now have a typo in your question: SetName and SetItemName, one or the other, but not both ;-)